# How to receive messages/events from public internet in Kafka/Nifi cluster hosted in the private subnet of AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I am working on a project were lots of machines/sensors will be sending messages to Kafka/Nifi cluster directly. This machine/sensors will be pushing messages from public internet not from the corporate network. We are using a Hortonworks distribution on the AWS cloud.

My question is: what is the best architectural practice to setup Kafka /Nifi cluster for such use cases, I don't want to put my cluster in the public subnet in order to receive messages from the public internet.

Can you please help me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you shouldn't expose your Kafka to the world. Therefore "sensor data directly to Kafka" is the wrong approach, IMO. At least, without using some SSL channel

You could allow a specific subnet of your external devices to reach the internal subnet, assuming you know that range, however I think your better option here is to use either Minifi or Streamsets SDC which are event collectors sitting on the sensors, which can encrypt traffic to an open Nifi or Streamsets cluster, which can then forward events to the internal Kafka cluster. You already have Nifi apparently, and therefore Minifi was built for this purpose

Another option could be the Kafka REST proxy, but you'll still need to setup authentication / security layers around it

Comment: we have some set of IP's those will be sending request/events to the Kafka.. other approach is that machine/sensor/server can send tcp messages from public internet.

Comment: Well, all messages are hopefully TCP. Kafka also operates on TCP. Not sure what you're saying

Comment: @ cricket_007 what are the options if we dont have to use Minifi ?

Comment: SSL encrypted Kafka packets, probably. Not really sure

Comment: @crickey_007, If we go for SSL Kafka packets, then where do we need to push this packets, Kafka cluster is in private subnet. Do we need to have a Gateway in public subnet? In order to route messages to Kafka cluster hosted in private subnet.

Comment: You need to enable SSL at the broker level https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security

Comment: sure we will enable ssl at the broker level, but how this messages will reach to Kafka cluster hosted in private subnet.

Comment: You need *some externally open port* This is where NiFi + Minifi, or Kafka Rest Proxy, or SDC Edge Collector help, as mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use [AWS IoT](https://aws.amazon.com/iot-core/features/?nc1=h_ls) to receive the devices communication, this option gives you a security layer and isolates you HDF sandbox from the internet.

> AWS IoT Core provides mutual authentication and encryption at all points of connection, so that data is never exchanged between devices and AWS IoT Core without a proven identity.

Then import the information with a NiFi processor.